# Set interval for autoplay carousel in materialize design

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

Right now i am using materialize design framework for User interface. And i am using carousel in materialize but carousel image is not move or auto play. I want to set some interval of time to auto play images.

```js
      $('.carousel').carousel({
            dist:0,
            shift:0,
            padding:20, 
           interval:100
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


 <div class="carousel">
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
    <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a very old version of jquery, change it for a newer and this example work, and if you want that the transition could be automatic you could use an interval and go to the next using the carousel method.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel({dist:0});
        window.setInterval(function(){$('.carousel').carousel('next')},500)
     });
```

```css
div.carousel a.carousel-item{
  width: 50px;  
}
img{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
           
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <div class="carousel">
            <a class="carousel-item" href="#one!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1"></a>
            <a class="carousel-item" href="#two!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2"></a>
            <a class="carousel-item" href="#three!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3"></a>
            <a class="carousel-item" href="#four!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4"></a>
            <a class="carousel-item" href="#five!"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5"></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't want 3d effect. I want to only plain carousel.

Comment: If you like my question then voting up, help to others.

Comment: Can we decrease the size of images.

Comment: I changed the css rules. but please, don't change the scope of the question, if you want make another question please post a new one.

Comment: If i scroll horizontal by mouse then it will not stop.

Comment: you should make another question, you asked for the interval and it was solved in the two answers.

Comment: Can we next and prev button ?

Answer (score 4):

The Materialize Carousel doesn't have an autoplay feature; I think it's designed to stay static until the user interacts with it.

It does however expose methods to move to the next slide so you could create an interval to update the carousel to the next slide e.g.

```
setInterval(function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel('next');
}, 1000);
```

You might want to name the callback for `setInterval` so you can clear it if you want the user to stop the carousel rotating if it becomes annoying.

Here's a quick [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6e87aou6/4/) to demonstrate.

Comment: I don't want 3d effect. I want to only plain carousel.

Comment: As per the docs you will just need to add the **carousel-slider** class to the carousel div i.e. ```<div class="carousel carousel-slider">```.  Also, some people seem to be having issues with [broken / half-width images](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2741).  Just add the ```full_width: true``` configuration option when initialising the carousel.  I had this problem when I tried it and making it 'full width' resolved it.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var carousel_interval = 1000;
    $('.carousel').carousel();
    var int;
    function run(){
        int = setInterval(function()
        { 
            $('.carousel').carousel('next');
        }, carousel_interval);
    }
    function stop(){
    clearInterval(int);
    }
    $('.carousel').hover(stop, run);     
    });
```

Comment: I like this answer, i just would add  run();  stop(); (after  $('.carousel').hover(stop, run); )   to run automatically, and remove previous intervals respectively.